# Can We Play a video in black and white

Tags: iphone

i have to play a video which is not black and white.i need to play it as black and white in iphone .can we do this.if yes then how to do ???

Comment: Is this programming related? Perhaps this belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly, doesnt seem that the MPMoviePlayerController gives you the ability to adjust such a feature, so i would say it is not possible right now with the build in movie player.

Answer (score 2):

Using the right blend mode, and painting a white rectangle (or is it black) on top of the view with the video, may accomplish what you want.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/drawingwithquartz2d.pdf

Comment: i added a view on to the movie player view and in drawrect method i am setting CGBlendMode to kCGBlendModeHardLight,and tried some other combnation but still not able to get black and white movie

Comment: Try it with just an image instead of a movie, just to make sure you got it right.